# How to extract one specific column (no header, say column 2) from multiple csv files using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, csv

I have 23 csv files. Each file contains two columns. I only want second column to be an output (output can be either csv or xlsx file; Name of the file = Banks_2008_2014.some extension). I want to get the second column of the first file and place it into the first column of the output file.

```
$excel_test = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel_test.visible =$true
$excel_test.DisplayAlerts =$true

$excel_test|select-object |format-table -autosize

$excelFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path     C:\SNOWPACK\Samarth\1_Banks\AllPro_Banks_Point1 -Include *.csv -Recurse

Freach ($i in $excelFiles)
{
$excel_test.workbook.worksheet.column.item($i) = $i[1]
}
```

Error: Unable to index into (System.IO).File.Info

**Examples:**

File_1

```
Column_1 Column_2
  0.1      0.11
  0.2      0.45
  0.35     0.6
  0.25     0.8
  0.33     0.1
```

File_2

```
Column_1 Column_2
 0.9       0.2   
 0.2       0.11
 0.45      0.4
 0.34      0.6
```

Result should look like this

```
Column_1 Column_2
  0.11     0.2
  0.45     0.11
  0.6      0.4
  0.8      0.6
  0.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are getting just the second columns from a collection of csv files?

```powershell
$path = "C:\SNOWPACK\Samarth\1_Banks\AllPro_Banks_Point1\*.csv"
Get-Content $path | ForEach-Object{$_.Split(",")[1]} | set-content C:\SNOWPACK\Samarth\1_Banks\AllPro_Banks_Point1\Banks_2008_2014.csv
```

That will extract the second item from every line in the csv file collection. This is of course assuming your csv files are formed well. No commas inside quotes.

Guessing your error was coming from `(get-content $File.)` since the parser would have seen you trying to access a propery of `$file` wherein none was specified.

**Update from Question**

It would seem you weren't as clear with original question. Adding the columns together is a different ball game but it can be done.

```powershell
$inputPath = "C:\SNOWPACK\Samarth\1_Banks\AllPro_Banks_Point1"
# Create a multidimensional array of all the files. 
$allFiles = @()
Get-ChildItem -Path $inputPath -Include "*.csv" -Recurse | ForEach-Object{$allFiles += ,@($_ | Get-Content | ForEach-Object{$_.Split(",")[1]})}
Write-Host "Collected $($allFiles.Count) files" -ForegroundColor Green

# Determine the length of the longest row
$maxRows = $allFiles | ForEach-Object{$_.Count} | Measure-Object -Maximum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Maximum
Write-Host "Highest Row Count: $maxRows"  -ForegroundColor Green

# Next line will clear the file. Uncomment it if that is what you are looking for.
#Clear-Content c:\temp\newfile.csv

For($rowIndex = 0; $rowIndex -lt $maxRows; $rowIndex++ ){
    # Build each row individually
    $row = @()
    For($fileIndex = 0; $fileIndex -lt $allFiles.Count; $fileIndex++ ){
        # Build an array of all the elements from each file in this row
        $row += $allFiles[$fileIndex][$rowIndex]
    }
    # Create proper delimeted row using -join and ouput to file.
    $row -join "," | Add-Content c:\temp\newfile.csv
}
```

This should also work if the files are of variable length and if some of the rows contain empty entries.

**Edit for 2.0**

Fixed how the output was working. This might not be the most efficient way but if your files are small it will work just fine. Call `Add-Content` for each row. Notice the `Clear-Content` that is commented out.

Comment: How can set up each file content in each column? Because currently I am exporting 2 column of all the csv files in one continuous column of the new csv file (Banks_2008_2014.csv)?

Comment: I tried to modify the code. I have 23 csv files. Each file contains two columns. I only want second column to be an output (output can be either csv or xlsx file; Name of the file = Banks_2008_2014.some extension). I want to get the second column of the first file and place it into the first column of the output file.

Comment: Hey Matt, Thank you for your help. The file is created but the columns are not filled. I have given an example of what I want my output file to look like.

Comment: @Samarth I follow what you want. Are your files not comma delimited then? Since they are not in your example. My solution requires commas and would need to be changed. What is the output of `$allfiles`  after it is populated?

Comment: After, I ran your code. I got output of the $allfiles. With reference to my above example, all the second columns are selected but the output is in just one column. I want the second column-second file's output to be in the second column of the Result_file. Sorry if my previous question was not explained well in detail.

Comment: @Samarth What is your PowerShell verion (`Get-Host`). Are you files comma delimited? Did you see the green line "Collected 23 files"?

Comment: My powershell version is 2.0. No, there are no commas in any of my 23 files. Yes, I did see the green line reading "Collected 23 files".

Comment: @Samarth Ok this changes things a little. I will test this in PowerShell 2.0 to be safe and account for the files being space/tab delimited. Is your data just numbers? If the data in the first two columns contains space its another issue. Then I would guess your file is position delimited.

Comment: Yes, My data is all number. Additionally, When I opened one of the file in Notepad++ the columns were seperated by ",". This suggests that the data is "," delimited

Comment: So it is comma delimited then. Ok thanks for letting me know before we went down that path. I will check that my logic works on 2.0

Comment: I think I know what it is `$newFile` is null as it is not capturing the output. I think this was a 2.0 issue. Do you see ouptut on screen when you change the line `$newFile = For($r.... ` to `For($r....`

Comment: Yes, I do see the correct output on the screen when I removed the "$newfile = ". I changed that line so it reads For ($r....

Comment: Exporting this is a pain. When I extended the line $row -join ","  to $row -join "," | Set-Content C:\SNOWPACK\Samarth\1_Banks\AllPro_Banks_Point1\newfile.csv. It provided me with only the last columns

Comment: @Samarth I will fix that. I just wanted to know what the issue was. Update is coming soon

Comment: Thank you so much. I am trying to learn this with trial and error. Running each of your code to understand your logic. Trying to build this in R too.

Comment: @Samarth check the update now and let me now. Side note. this could also have been done with the Excel object but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Yes, The Add-content command line does put the entire content instead of just the last two columns. Long story short, the code works.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have headers, just make some up:

```
Import-Csv C:\SNOWPACK\Samarth\1_Banks\AllPro_Banks_Point1\*.csv -Header (1..10) |
Select -ExpandProperty  '2' |
set-content C:\SNOWPACK\Samarth\1_Banks\AllPro_Banks_Point1\Banks_2008_2014.csv
```